# 4 Pin Potentiometer Identification

Tags: identification, potentiometer

[image]I am trying to repair a very expensive manlift joystick. I had great luck soldering in a new potentiometer on a different machine and getting it back to work, but this other machine has a potentiometer that I have not seen before.

It has 4 pins total, three like a normal rotary potentiometer and then a fourth across from the other three pins.

It is a Clarostat U-10K-OHM Type EJ pot. It has another number stamped "99148B 9507"

Clarostat has been purchased by Honeywell, so I am having a hard time finding any catalogs or datasheets for this guy. Can anyone point me in the right direction or advise what the fourth pin may be for? Would replacing with a standard three pin pot be a possibility?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, that looks pretty much like the photo I posted- center tap 99.9% sure. Linear-taper extended-life 10K pot with a center tap (and whatever shaft and bushing length spec there is- I guess 6.35mm x whatever length). All that stuff was customizable if you bought a reasonable quantity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I second Spehro in what he thinks it is: an heavy-duty pot with additional center tap.

[TT Electronics](http://www.bitechnologies.com/) seems to sell a product similar to the part sported in your photo ([datasheet](http://www.bitechnologies.com/pdfs/p270.pdf)).

[image]

Here is an excerpt from the datasheet with the technical drawing:

[image]

And here is the electrical circuit:

[image]

Even if it is not what you are looking for, it may be a starting point.

Comment: Nice find. In stock at Digikey for < $15 USD.

Comment: That is perfect. Just ordered from Mouser 10.98ea for dust sealed.

Answer (score 4):

Not familiar with that series, but it appears to be an extended-life pot.

There are two possibilities for the 4th connection. The first is that it is a center-tap on the element. This might allow them to control the output at the neutral position of the joystick better. The second (and less likely one) is that it's a ground connection.

A quick test with an ohmmeter should settle the matter. Here is a picture of a center-tapped 10K pot. It would measure 5K from either end of the element to the opposite (center-tap) pin. The wiper would short to the center tap when in the center of rotation.

[image]

Comment: Since he is looking for a replacement, a quick check with a multimeter might not be a good option

Comment: @PlasmaHH even if there is not a working pot on another axis it would serve to rule out the ground option(but I think that's redundant given the photo the op added)

Answer (score 4):

Four-terminal potentiometers were common at one stage on hi-fi volume controls to give automatic "loudness" control - see [What's a potentiometer with four terminals in this schematic?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235432/whats-a-potentiometer-with-four-terminals-in-this-schematic/235437#235437) - but these were logrithmic law and a joystick is more likely to be linear.

My guess is that it's a linear pot and that the centre-tap is used to provide a definite GND or reference to assist with a deadzone in the centre of the pot. This would be intended to prevent creep when the joystick is centred.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUYi9I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I found a Clarostat brochure on [Stephen Engineering](https://stevenengineering.com/tech_support/PDFs/31CLAROSTAT.pdf) and they seem to be handling the product now. They don't have any four terminal pots listed.