# Equivalent replacement for a centered 4pin potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer

[image]

I need some help in understanding the pots pictured above.
How does this 4pin pot work? What is the function of the 4th pin?

Would this be the correct replacement if I want to replace the centered pot with plain resistors?

[image]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235432/whats-a-potentiometer-with-four-terminals-in-this-schematic

Comment: Thanks! I see, it's a center tap and sits in the middle of the resistive track? So we have terminal1 -  125k - center tap  - 125k - terminal3. And the wiper covers the range from 0 to 250k. Right?

Comment: It might be better, in the configuration shown, to think of the potentiometer as 0k - 125k - 0k or as seen from one outside pin the 0%/50%/100% resistance will be 0k/125k/125k and 125k/125k/0k for the other outside pin.